# How do I merge 2 videos with a fade transition?

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avplayer, avasset, avmutablecomposition

I'm trying two merge 2 videos with a 2 second overlap. In this overlap I'd like to fade the second video in (or fade the first one out to reveal the second, either one would be great).

The first video is fading out 2 seconds before the end as intended, but as it fades I get a black screen instead of the second video fading in. At the end of video 1, video 2 shows up half way through its fade in animation.

What am I doing wrong with the tracks that I can't see them overlapping? Below is my code

```html
func setupVideo() {
        
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "demoVideoTwo", ofType: "mp4")!)
    let assetOne = AVAsset(url: url)
    
    let urlTwo = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "demoVideoThree", ofType: "mp4")!)
    let assetTwo = AVAsset(url: urlTwo)
            
    let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()
    var instructions = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction]()
    var mainInstructionList = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction]()
    var lastTime = CMTime.zero
    
    // Create Track One

    guard let videoTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)), let audioTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)) else {
        return
    }
    
    // Setup AVAsset 1

    let timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: assetOne.duration)
    
    do {
        try videoTrack.insertTimeRange(timeRange, of: assetOne.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0], at: lastTime)
        
        try audioTrack.insertTimeRange(timeRange, of: assetOne.tracks(withMediaType: .audio)[0], at: lastTime)
        
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    
    // Setup Layer Instruction 1

    let layerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videoTrack)

    let duration = CMTime(seconds: 2, preferredTimescale: 60)
    let transitTime = CMTime(seconds: 2, preferredTimescale: 60)
    let insertTime = CMTimeSubtract(assetOne.duration, transitTime)
    let instRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: insertTime, duration: duration)
    layerInstruction.setOpacityRamp(fromStartOpacity: 1.0, toEndOpacity: 0.0, timeRange: instRange)
    instructions.append(layerInstruction)

    let mainInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
    mainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: lastTime, duration: assetOne.duration)
    mainInstruction.layerInstructions = instructions

    mainInstructionList.append(mainInstruction)

    lastTime = CMTimeAdd(lastTime, assetOne.duration)
    
    
    // Create Track One

    guard let videoTrackTwo = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)), let audioTrackTwo = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)) else {
        return
    }
    
    // Setup AVAsset 2

    let transitionTime = CMTime(seconds: 2, preferredTimescale: 60)
    let newLastTime = CMTimeSubtract(assetOne.duration, transitionTime)

    let timeRangeTwo = CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: assetTwo.duration)

    do {
        try videoTrackTwo.insertTimeRange(timeRangeTwo, of: assetTwo.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0], at: newLastTime)

        try audioTrackTwo.insertTimeRange(timeRangeTwo, of: assetTwo.tracks(withMediaType: .audio)[0], at: newLastTime)

    } catch {
       print(error)
    }
    
    
    // Setup Layer Instruction 2

    let layerInstructionTwo = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videoTrackTwo)
    let durationTwo = CMTime(seconds: 4, preferredTimescale: 60)
    let instRangeTwo = CMTimeRangeMake(start: newLastTime, duration: durationTwo)
    layerInstructionTwo.setOpacityRamp(fromStartOpacity: 0.0, toEndOpacity: 1.0, timeRange: instRangeTwo)
    instructions.append(layerInstructionTwo)

    let mainInstructionTwo = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
    mainInstructionTwo.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: lastTime, duration: assetTwo.duration)
    mainInstructionTwo.layerInstructions = instructions
    
    mainInstructionList.append(mainInstructionTwo)
    
    // Setup Video Composition

    let mainComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    mainComposition.instructions = mainInstructionList
    mainComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 60)
    mainComposition.renderSize = videoTrack.naturalSize
            
    let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: mixComposition)
    item.videoComposition = mainComposition
    
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
    
    let playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer = {
        let layer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        layer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        return layer
    }()
    
    let playerWidth: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
    let videoHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * 9 / 16
            
    playerLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: playerWidth, height: videoHeight)
    self.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Don't create AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction for each 
video track and don't assign instructions to it each time. Instead, create AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction just once right before create AVMutableVideoComposition then assign instructions to that.

Here is the code working that way you want.

```
func setupVideo() {

    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "demoVideoTwo", ofType: "mp4")!)
    let assetOne = AVAsset(url: url)

    let urlTwo = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "demoVideoTwo", ofType: "mp4")!)
    let assetTwo = AVAsset(url: urlTwo)

    let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()
    var instructions = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction]()
    var lastTime = CMTime.zero

    // Create Track One

    guard let videoTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)), let audioTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)) else {
        return
    }

    // Setup AVAsset 1

    let timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: assetOne.duration)

    do {
        try videoTrack.insertTimeRange(timeRange, of: assetOne.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0], at: lastTime)

        try audioTrack.insertTimeRange(timeRange, of: assetOne.tracks(withMediaType: .audio)[0], at: lastTime)

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    // Setup Layer Instruction 1

    let layerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videoTrack)

    let duration = CMTime(seconds: 2, preferredTimescale: 60)
    let transitTime = CMTime(seconds: 2, preferredTimescale: 60)
    let insertTime = CMTimeSubtract(assetOne.duration, transitTime)
    let instRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: insertTime, duration: duration)
    layerInstruction.setOpacityRamp(fromStartOpacity: 1.0, toEndOpacity: 0.0, timeRange: instRange)
    instructions.append(layerInstruction)

    lastTime = CMTimeAdd(lastTime, assetOne.duration)


    // Create Track One

    guard let videoTrackTwo = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)), let audioTrackTwo = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)) else {
        return
    }

    // Setup AVAsset 2

    let transitionTime = CMTime(seconds: 2, preferredTimescale: 60)
    let newLastTime = CMTimeSubtract(assetOne.duration, transitionTime)

    let timeRangeTwo = CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: assetTwo.duration)

    do {
        try videoTrackTwo.insertTimeRange(timeRangeTwo, of: assetTwo.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0], at: newLastTime)

        try audioTrackTwo.insertTimeRange(timeRangeTwo, of: assetTwo.tracks(withMediaType: .audio)[0], at: newLastTime)

    } catch {
       print(error)
    }

    // Setup Layer Instruction 2

    let layerInstructionTwo = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videoTrackTwo)
    layerInstructionTwo.setOpacity(1.0, at: newLastTime)
    instructions.append(layerInstructionTwo)

    // Setup Video Composition

    let mainInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
    mainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: CMTimeAdd(newLastTime, assetTwo.duration))
    mainInstruction.layerInstructions = instructions

    let mainComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    mainComposition.instructions = [mainInstruction]
    mainComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 60)
    mainComposition.renderSize = videoTrack.naturalSize

    let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: mixComposition)
    item.videoComposition = mainComposition

    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)

    let playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer = {
        let layer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        layer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        return layer
    }()

    let playerWidth: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
    let videoHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * 9 / 16

    playerLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: playerWidth, height: videoHeight)
    self.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
}
```